# Get path two levels up in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My requirement is to get the path two levels up from where the batch file is being executed:
Suppose my batch file is located at:
D:\testfolder\system\tools\configuration task\conf.bat

I use the following code in batch file:

```
SET BATCH_FILE_DIR=%~dp0
echo %BATCH_FILE_DIR%
SET PATH_TWO_LEVELS_UP=?????
```

I tried searching over the net, but could not find anything useful.
For me, something should replace `?????` which would set,
    PATH_TWO_LEVELS_UP to D:\testfolder\system\

Also, it should work for UNC Path. Suppose if the same batch file is available at:
\\pc-dummy\testfolder\system\tools\configuration task\conf.bat

If open the above location in explorer and double click on batch file,
the variable PATH_TWO_LEVELS_UP should be set to \\pc-dummy\testfolder\system\

What should come in place of `?????` that would work for local drive as well as for UNC Paths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0..\..") do set "PATH_TWO_LEVELS_UP=%%~fa"
echo %PATH_TWO_LEVELS_UP%
```

Get a reference to the required folder using a `for` command and set the variable to the full path to the referenced folder

Comment: Thanks this helped. Marked as answer :)